# Get how many times visited a location in Android

Tags: android, gps

In my app I have to display how many times a user visited a location. I have done it by saving location details to DB in onlocationchanged method. But even if i am sitting idle getting frequent calls to this method and lot of entries are inserted into DB. How can I do implement this. Thanks in advance

```
 @Override  
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {         
    if (location != null && location.getLatitude() != 0
                            && location.getLongitude() != 0) {

                        Preferences.setLattitude(context, location.getLatitude());
                        Preferences.setLongitude(context, location.getLongitude());
                                    Preferences.setCurrentLocation(context, Utility
                                .getAddress(location.getLatitude(),
                                        location.getLongitude(), context));

                        saveCurrentLocationDetails();       } }
```

Comment: Why don't you check if the lat and lon are already present in the db? And if it's present, instead of saving the location, increment the count for "times visited".

Comment: @JoelFernandes   Some times getting different values lat long values for the same location

Comment: @JoelFernandes  Also if user is not moving from that location I don't want to increment the count

Comment: measure the location difference between two consecutive location inserted, if difference is above threshold, then increment the location visited count, else discard it, even no need to save frequent same location in the db.

Comment: @Karan what value is best for threshold

Comment: 200 meter would be appropriate.

Comment: @Karan thank you karan. Please add it as answer.

Comment: visited a location is not exact,be near to a location would be better,I think:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please measure the location difference between two consecutive locations inserted, if difference is above threshold, then increment the location visited count, else discard it, even no need to save frequent same location in the DB, also keep the threshold value of difference is 200 meters.